# Postgres query multiple where clauses not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following notifications table:

```
| id (PK - INT) | user_id (UUID) | text (Text) | show_after (Date) default NULL |
```

What I'm wanting todo is select all the notifs for the `user_id`, I also want to ensure that we DON'T show notifs where the `show_after` date is in future.

So if I want to show a notification after 5 days, I'd set `show_after = NOW() + 5 days`.

For some reason the query I've setup is behaving weirdly and will ALWAYS return the notifications where show_after === any date, even though some of the notifs have a show_after date set in the future.

Here is the query I tried:

```
select * from activities where user_id = '<uuid>' OR show_after = null AND 
show_after <= NOW();
```

I also tried switching around the OR/ANDs without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses to control the logic

```
select * from activities 
where user_id = '<uuid>' 
and (
     show_after <= NOW()
   OR
     show_after IS NULL
    )
;
```

Additionally in SQL you must use `IS NULL` to determine if there is no value. Using the equal symbol will not work (`NULL = NULL` is always false).

Comment: Awesome! Note that I changed the date query to: `show_after <= NOW()` (<=) (updated this in my question )

Comment: `<=` makes sense, changed the answer to suit. cheers. in future queries always be on the lookout for `or` as it can have unexpected effects with he parentheses to limit it.